# Lists in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form:

```
{
 {0.185794, {α -> 5.8794,  χ -> 3.14159}}
,{0.206365, {α -> 6.07943, χ -> 3.14159}}
}
```

How can I transform this list such that it contains triplets of the form:

```
{5.8794, 3.14159 }
```

That is, I want to drop the first element and retain the next two elements without the variables.

**Edit:**

The complete list is:

```
  list = {{0.`, {α -> 7.40402817067928`*^-10, χ -> 
  1.5707963199759551`}}, {-1.1102230246251565`*^-16, {α -> 
  0.`, χ -> 
  1.570796310785471`}}, {-1.3322676295501878`*^-15, {α -> 
  6.283185236232465`, χ -> 
  1.5707962926795942`}}, {-7.771561172376096`*^-16, {α -> 
  6.283185242937872`, χ -> 
  1.5707962817101633`}}, {-1.4432899320127035`*^-15, {α -> 
  6.283185213845592`, χ -> 
  1.5707962574691037`}}, {-1.6653345369377348`*^-15, {α -> 
  6.283185168970566`, χ -> 
  1.5707962135597096`}}, {0.000039743185786034196`, {α -> 
  6.101378684908873`, χ -> 
  1.416341223365662`}}, {0.04502974573215446`, {α -> 
  4.8669662247178715`, χ -> 
  0.8684522135648123`}}, {0.14619238131191453`, {α -> 
  3.9372113567750526`, χ -> 
  1.0267300878173935`}}, {-0.03365091466576414`, {α -> 
  6.283185307179586`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.0387037789988178`, {α -> 
  5.27985616378398`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.5500615962645923`, {α -> 
  3.14159261319097`, χ -> 
  1.5707963347517426`}}, {0.1502504642607271`, {α -> 
  5.679720812825692`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.18579431483854147`, {α -> 
  5.8793987995998735`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.20636475575559726`, {α -> 
  6.07942545836383`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.2116046084330751`, {α -> 
  6.279301995689666`, χ -> 
  3.141592653589793`}}, {0.20176755574756772`, {α -> 
  0.08350912308643653`, χ -> 
  3.941791666553896`*^-9}}, {0.1776933003532231`, {α -> 
  0.08350912308643653`, χ -> 
  3.941791666553896`*^-9}}, {0.6036070488425198`, {α -> 
  3.1415926143838626`, χ -> 
  1.5707962914138776`}}, {0.5018188905655654`, {α -> 
  3.141592611777223`, χ -> 1.5707963036550594`}}};
```

Answer (score 10):

```
{\[Alpha], \[Chi]} /. list[[All, 2]]
```

or

```
list[[All, 2, All, 2]]
```

If `list` is very huge, the second method has much higher efficiency.

Comment: This is the best answer, I think, just using `Part`.

Answer (score 8):

You may use [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html), [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/<code>Values.html), and [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

```
Values@*Last /@ list
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{0.185794, {α -> 5.8794, χ -> 3.14159}},
   {0.206365, {α -> 6.07943, χ -> 3.14159}}};

{#2[[1, 2]], #2[[2, 2]]} & @@@ list
```

> {{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}

Also

```
Last /@ Last[#] & /@ list
```

and

```
Extract[list, {All, 2, {1, 2}, 2}]
```

Comment: What if I had a huge list? What would be the syntax then?

Comment: I'll post the complete list in the question.

Comment: It would work for all the sublists.

Comment: Awesome. Can you send me the link to the documentation where I can read more on this? I tried searching multiple times for a solution to this option but to no avail.

Comment: [Apply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [Pure Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: Also, I have two lists. Each list has the same number of sublists. What I want to do is that I want to pick up the element from the first sublist of list 1, and add it as the first co-ordinate in the first sublist of list 2 -- and repeat for all sublists. How do I go about it?

Comment: @JunaidAftab. It is recommended that you post your complete question in your original post. Please add your last question to your original post so that we can actually help you solve your problem. I recommend giving a minimal example of your two lists and what your intended output is.

Answer (score 6):

`Cases[list, {_, {a_ -> x_, b_ -> y_}} :> {x, y}]`

Comment: Also: `list /. { _, {α ->x_ , χ ->y_}} -> {x, y}` should work. There is no need for a delayed rule here, I believe (I'm writing this in the blind).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0.185794, {a -> 5.8794, b -> 3.14159}}, {0.206365, {a -> 6.07943, b -> 3.14159}}};
```

Pre-define replacement pattern `p` for better comparabilty

```
p = {_, x : {(_ -> _) ..}} :> Values[x];

list /. p
```

{{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}

```
Replace[list, p, {1}]
```

{{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}

```
Cases[p] @ list
```

{{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `GatherBy`:

```
list = {{0.185794, {α -> 5.8794, χ -> 3.14159}}, 
        {0.206365, {α -> 6.07943, χ -> 3.14159}}};

Splice /@ Values@GatherBy[list, x_ /; Head[x] === Rule][[All, All, 2]]

(*{{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases`:

```
Values@Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten@#, Except[_Rule]], 2] &@list

(*{{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
list = {{0.185794, {α -> 5.8794, χ -> 3.14159}},
   {0.206365, {α -> 6.07943, χ -> 3.14159}}};

Lookup[Last@#, {α, χ}, {}] & /@ list
```

> {{5.8794, 3.14159}, {6.07943, 3.14159}}